# Is it safe to call Kotlin suspend function recursively?

Tags: kotlin, recursion, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

I have an API which may respond "try again a bit later". I would like to call the function recursively in this case (to propagate cancellation automatically).

Simplified example:

```
suspend fun loadData() {
    runCatching { someApi.loadData() }
        .onSuccess { response ->
            if (response is Response.TryAgain) {
                delay(1000)
                loadData()
            }
        }
}
```

If I understand correctly, this code should not cause `StackOverflowError` (in contrast to regular non-suspend recursive functions).

I got the idea from [the article by Roman Elizarov](https://medium.com/@elizarov/deep-recursion-with-coroutines-7c53e15993e3), but I don't use a `DeepRecursiveFunction` here.

I wrote [some tests](https://gist.github.com/gmk57/113b930588b51159c2bed8deb1ade1ca) for Android, and it seems that:

1. `suspend` function without suspension points throws `StackOverflowError` at depth around 1000-4000 (just like non-suspend one)
2. `suspend` function with suspension points (`yield()` or `delay()`) allows to reach depth of 1-2 millions, where `OutOfMemoryError` happens

Is this behavior documented somewhere, or is it just an implementation detail which may change in the future? I haven't found an answer in [coroutines design document](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/coroutines.md) or [coroutines guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutines-guide.html), as well as here on SO.

Overall, is it a good idea to use this pattern, if call depth will be well under a million? Are there better cancellable solutions?

Comment: In this simplified example, [tailrec](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#tail-recursive-functions) modifier looks to be a perfect option. Is it suitable in your real case?

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Unfortunately, real use case includes `try/catch` (or `runCatching`), which is not supported by `tailrec`. I edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

If [tailrec](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#tail-recursive-functions) optimization is not applicable in your case, you may manually convert your recursion function into while-loop:

```kotlin
suspend fun loadData() {
    var getResponse = false
    while (!getResponse) {
        runCatching { someApi.loadData() }
            .onSuccess { response ->
                if (response is Response.TryAgain) {
                    delay(1000)
                } else {
                    getResponse = true
                }
            }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Yes, I currently have something like this. But recursive solution is shorter and (for me) also logically clearer, so I'd rather go with it. Could you please add some reasons to prefer this one?

Comment: It saves you from `StackOverflowError` regardless of retries count, but, yes, it's looks not that nice as recursive one. You may mix this approach with [Template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) so it could be reusable, while all "bad parts" will be written once and hidden in template.

Comment: Well, "retry on error" can be nicely abstracted away with smth like [runRetrying](https://gist.github.com/gmk57/77f25792f95b60b8eab4d9f0a7d1b38e). Here it might need ~4 lambdas though (operation itself, "try again" checker, valid response processing, error processing), which looks... a bit strange. :)  

I still hope somebody will say definitely: is recursive solution safe or not.